# Synonyms for "copying a person"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a verb to describe "copying someone's pose, style, get up, etc."?

Comment: Look up synonyms for *aping*, *imitation* as well as the meaning of *a la*.

Comment: As you can see from the wide variety of suggestions so far, it is not clear what you are asking for. Copying by accident? deliberately? with good intentions? in order to hurt? publicly? in private? Please edit your question to provide further detail. An example sentence or other context would be useful, too.

Comment: Judging by the title alone, I'd suggest _cloning._ You might also want to check out [ell.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Copying" is in itself a way to describe that, but I imagine you're looking for something a bit more specific.

You could say that person is being your '[doppelganger](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/doppelganger)", which is a good word for a double of someone, with a slight connotation to being an 'evil' double from its German roots.

Being a "[copycat](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/copycat)" is a common term used to describe when someone is doing the exact same thing you do in the exact same way.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of is [*copycat*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/copycat)

> cop·y·cat  (kp-kt) Informal
>   n.
>   One that closely imitates or mimics another.
>
> v. cop·y·cat·ted, cop·y·cat·ting, cop·y·cats
>
> v.intr.
>   To act as an imitator or mimic.
>
> v.tr.
>   To imitate closely; mimic.
>
> adj.
>   Closely imitating or following another: a copycat version of a successful product; a copycat crime.

Answer (score 1):

[Mirroring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirroring_%28psychology%29) - is a psychological term to describe the behaviour in which one person copies another person usually while in social interaction with them. It may include miming gestures, movements, body language, muscle tensions, expressions, tones, eye movements, breathing, tempo, accent, attitude, choice of words or metaphors, and other aspects of communication. It is often observed among couples or close friends.

OR

[Mimic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mimic) - [imitate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/imitate) (someone or their actions or words), typically in order to entertain or ridicule